# Работа с AsyncTask в Android

Tags: android, java

Пытаюсь создать поток для вращения картинки, сделал все по инструкции начинаю вызывать а оно просто закрывает приложение. Код:

```
private class TransformMethod extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(Void... Void) {
         transform.preRotate(5, bmp.getWidth() / 2, bmp.getHeight() / 2);

         return null;
        }
    }
```

И метод вызова:

```
new TransformMethod().execute();
```

В чем проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста.

То что выдает Log-cat

```
    Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown during Landroid/os/AsyncTask;.<clinit>
threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at fat.fraddy.Player.onDraw(Player.java:40)
at fat.fraddy.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:272)
at fat.fraddy.GameView$GameThread.run(GameView.java:141)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
Sending signal. PID: 1155 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Есть подозрения, что матрица transform у вас объявлена в главном потоке, а вы к ней асинхронно обращаетесь. Стектрейс покажите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что внутри треда (каковым фактически является AsyncTask) вы пытаетесь обратиться к функциям оконной системы. Чтобы обратиться к функциям оконной системы надо запустить цикл обработки сообщений к оконной системе. В данном контексте это означает надо запустить `Looper.prepare()`. Подробнее [здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)

Comment: Делаю так:
Looper.prepare();
new TransformMethod().execute();
Все запускается но обхект исчезает с экрана, добавляю Looper.looper(); и вижу токо черный экран.

Comment: черный экран должен заставить включить воображение происходящего на экране =)

Comment: так нарно и сделаю)) Пусть представляют что там игра...

Comment: Шутки шутками но ничего не получается((( Помимо бага с координатами которые теперь не передаются, начались глюки после того как я вставил Looper.prepear(), теперь игра закрывается с ошибкой неизвестной, есть какие нибудь предложения?